# Function is not getting called anymore, when trying to dispatch a type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am currently trying to access my data using the Spotify API. This works very well. Thats the function I am using to get my Data. I assume the other stuff is not important. I can post that, if you need that.

```
export const getSpotifyUser = (access_token:string) =>{
     setAuthorizationHeader(access_token)
     axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me').then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
```

I have set up a redux store and trying to put the credentials into the store, by dispatching the right type (SET_USER).

```
 export const getSpotifyUser = (access_token:string) => (dispatch: any) => {
console.log("function is not called") // Function is not even called why ?
         setAuthorizationHeader(access_token)
         axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me').then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
    dispatch ({
    type: SET_USER,
    payload: res.data
        })
      }
```

but as soon as I use dispatch, the function is no longer called.
I really do not see my mistake. Is that a typescript error ?. ( I am using react typescript)

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export default store
```

rootReducer.ts

```
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
    import userReducer from './User/userReducer'
    
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      user: userReducer,
    })
    
    export default rootReducer
```

userReducer.ts

```
 import { AnyAction } from 'redux'

import { SET_USER } from './userTypes'

interface Credentials {
  username: string
  email: string
  profilepicture: string
  id: number
}

interface InitialState {
  authenticated: boolean
  loadding: boolean
  credentials?: Credentials
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  authenticated: false,
  loadding: false,
  credentials: {} as Credentials,
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction)  => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        credentials: action.payload,
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

Login.tsx ( I am making the login here. It is working fine, if am not using dispatch

```
 import {  IonButton } from '@ionic/react'
    
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
    
   
    import {
      getAuthorizeHref,
      getHashParams,
      removeHashParamsFromUrl,
      getSpotifyUser,
    } from '../../Helpers/login'
    
           const Login: React.FC = () => {
      // const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const hashParams = getHashParams()
        const access_token = hashParams.access_token
        // const expires_in = hashParams.expires_in
        removeHashParamsFromUrl()
      
        getSpotifyUser(access_token)
      }, [])
    return (
      <IonButton onClick={() => window.open(getAuthorizeHref(), '_self')}>
    )}
    export default Login
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you ? I don't know redux but I'm pretty sure your dispatch argument shouldn't go here, thats a wrong syntax. From what I understand you should call the dispatch method on your object.

Comment: Are you sure ? Thats the way i learned that. I am not using the dispatch Hook to be clear. https://youtu.be/m_u6P5k0vP0?t=22935 . For example he is doing that as well

Comment: Could you please post the code you mean ? :)

Comment: Ok actually the syntax is wrong, you forgot the second => arrow function man. But you should have a compiler that tells you that, or atleast log your typescript errors.

Comment: Oh sry I just  deleted the second => by mistake, while I was writing my post

Comment: I am pretty sure the syntax is wright. I assume my mistakes lies 
somewhere else

Comment: Provide code of the `rootReducer` and the code where you call `getSpotifyUser`

Comment: sure one minute please

Comment: @AndrewTvorch. I have posted everything you need

Comment: @DevMoutarde the syntax `const actionCreator = (args) => (dispatch) => {}` is called a "thunk" and it is a correct syntax as long as they have they right middleware, which they do.

Comment: @LindaPaiste he updated the code, thats not what was written at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're using typescript with react, I believe you have added the getSpotifyUser function to your interface, now if you want to access that i think you should call it like this

> props.getSpotifyUser(access_token)

and finally add it to your connect as a dispatch function that's wrapping your component

your login component should be like this one

```js
import {  IonButton } from '@ionic/react'
    
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {
  getAuthorizeHref,
  getHashParams,
  removeHashParamsFromUrl,
  getSpotifyUser,
} from '../../Helpers/login'

interface ILogin {
  getAuthorizeHref: () => any;
  getHashParams: () => any;
  removeHashParamsFromUrl: () => any;
  getSpotifyUser: (access_token) => any;
}

const Login: React.FC = (props: ILogin) => {
  // const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials)

  useEffect(() => {
    const hashParams = props.getHashParams()
    const access_token = hashParams.access_token
    // const expires_in = hashParams.expires_in
    props.removeHashParamsFromUrl()
  
    props.getSpotifyUser(access_token)
  }, [])
return (
  <IonButton onClick={() => window.open(props.getAuthorizeHref(), '_self')}>
)}
export default connect(null, {getAuthorizeHref, getHashParams, removeHashParamsFromUrl, getSpotifyUser})(Login)
```

Comment: No I did not add the getSpotifyUser in my interface. I do not need to do that. The functions worked fine, until I used (dispatch: any) => ...

Comment: Maybe I am wrong and do not see my mistake. Could you post the code you actually mean ?

Comment: the function was working fine until you attached dispatch to it?

Comment: have you wrapped your component with connect from react-redux?

Comment: No. I am using functional components. Wait I will post the whole code in Login.tsx

Comment: yes, it'd be better if you post the whole component

Comment: I have posted the whole code of the Login component

Comment: I have updated the answer, please follow that and also
follow this documentation for more details 
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: I can try that. But I do not get, why everything is working, if I do not use dispatch.  I know the approach you are using. But is Basicly the same as mine Idea

Comment: you have to follow the redux docs and maintain the structure for redux to work correctly on your application https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: Yeah I am doing that. I do not have to use connect sine Hooks

Comment: useDispatch() is the better alternative, but I am also not using that hook. I am passing an async function which is dispatching a type: The function is not even getting called. Also in your approach

Comment: any function that uses that dispatch is a redux action, and you have to follow the docs specifically to call that function, if you do not do that the function won't be getting called

Comment: Thank you very much, because of you I have found my mistake !!!

Answer (score 0):

Basicly Shamim has given the right answer.Any function that uses that dispatch is a redux action, and you have to follow the docs specifically to call that function. You have to use connect to dispatch actions. As an alternative you can use the dispatchHook. If am wrong please please correct me !!!!

Thats the right code I just had to correct Login.tsx

```
import { IonApp, IonButton } from '@ionic/react'

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {
  getAuthorizeHref,
  getHashParams,
  removeHashParamsFromUrl,
  getSpotifyUser,
} from '../../Helpers/login'

const style = {
  Logo: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    top: '70%',
  } as const,
}

const Login: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  // const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.credentials)

  useEffect(() => {
    const hashParams = getHashParams()
    const access_token = hashParams.access_token
    // const expires_in = hashParams.expires_in
    removeHashParamsFromUrl()
    console.log('halloeuseeffect')
    props.getSpotifyUser(access_token)
    console.log('halloeuseeffect')
  }, [])

  return (
    <IonApp>
      
     
          <IonButton onClick={() => window.open(getAuthorizeHref(), '_self')}>
            knsnan
        
    </IonApp>
  )
}

export default connect(null, {
  getSpotifyUser,
})(Login)
```